# Web Scraping using Python, requests.get() responses incomplete values for number exceeding 27 digits

Tags: python, html, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape shopee item information using python.

Take https://shopee.com.my/All%20in%20one%20pc%20Intel%20core%20I3/I5/I7%20Dual-core%208G%20RAM%20128%20gb%20SSD%20With%20optical%20drive%20CD%2023.8%20Inch%20computer%20Office%20Desktop%20All-in-one%20desktop%20Support%20WiFi-i.206039726.5859069631 as an example.

As it is using ajax, I am trying to extract it from: https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/item/get?itemid=5859069631&shopid=206039726

When I inspect it from chrome inspect, in preview & response, the images shows complete values(32 digits). But when I get the response values from requests.get(), the value only shows 27 digits.

in preview & response the values of 'images' are:

```
images: ["0cab02400aec16036fc22e1371e6ac82", "7822e2c23e97a127cc7d5e1f09ceeb05",…]
0: "0cab02400aec16036fc22e1371e6ac82"
1: "7822e2c23e97a127cc7d5e1f09ceeb05"
2: "30aafee6dea83815d0ef8f903ae83545"
3: "9e50205c2e35d906eecaa5c51efee1b1"
4: "36653bbf56bf3c3ee23e733505514a2e"
5: "3fbd12af05e09c4f8d7444f42950a560"
6: "66d3c8663071e841f22a0164207b9af5"
7: "8dd24dfe33310ac8a7aa2449a9d7cd5b"
8: "ad83672be0471df9f7d4328c8cc6b093"
```

requests.get() values are:

```
"images":["0cab02400aec16036fc22e1371e","7822e2c23e97a127cc7d5e1f09c","30aafee6dea83815d0ef8f903ae","9e50205c2e35d906eecaa5c51ef","36653bbf56bf3c3ee23e7335055","3fbd12af05e09c4f8d7444f4295","66d3c8663071e841f22a0164207","8dd24dfe33310ac8a7aa2449a9d","ad83672be0471df9f7d4328c8cc"]
```

the last 5 digits are missing.

code:

```
response = requests.get(url,cookies=cookie, headers=headers)

print(response.content)

if response.status_code == 200:

    item_info = response.text
```

How can I fix this and get the complete value? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@tadahjj can you link to the api documentation for that endpoint? It might tell you why it returns an incomplete id in the response - it will give us a little more to work with to diagnose the error, regardless.